# Terraform: Azure API Management Authorizations - Client Credentials

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I want to add an authorization to Azure API Management using Terraform. I don't find the corresponding Terraform resource; the closest one is azurerm_api_management_authorization_server but it does support all the properties like "Grant type", "Resource URL" and "Authorization Name."

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_authorization_server" "this" {
  count                        = length(var.apim_kv_secret_keys)
  name                         = "${var.api_management_name}-${lower(var.apim_kv_secret_keys[count.index])}"
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name          = var.api_management_name
  display_name                 = "${var.api_management_name}-${lower(var.apim_kv_secret_keys[count.index])}"

  grant_types = [
    "clientCredentials",
  ]
  authorization_methods = [
    "GET",
  ]
}
```

[image]

**Update: June-26**
I tried the suggested solution and found the below

[image]

Comment: What is the actual blocker here? @One Developer

Comment: Looks like the resource "azurerm_api_management_authorization_server" does support all the properties like "Grant type", "Resource URL" and "Authorization Name." to implement Authorizations in Azure APIM with Client Credentials as a Grant type. Can you throw an example?

Comment: Sure will work on it. @One Developer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to pass the resource URL you can use the `client_registration_endpoint` property because this is the URI of the page where this Authorization Server's resource/client registration is performed.

And for `grant_type` as `clientcredentials`, you can pass it as

`grant_types = ["clientCredentials", ]` as detailed below.

If you're using client credentials to authorize, you'll require the `token_endpoint` and one of the *bearer authentications sending methods.*

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
  name = "Jahnavi"
}

data "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "newjahapim"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_authorization_server" "example" {
  name                         = "test-server"
  api_management_name          = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  display_name                 = "Test Server"
  authorization_endpoint       = "https://example.mydomain.com/client/authorize"
  token_endpoint                = "https://example.com/token"
  client_id                    = "<clientID>"
  client_registration_endpoint = "https://testserver.com/client/register"
  bearer_token_sending_methods  = ["authorizationHeader"]

  grant_types = [
    "clientCredentials",
  ]
  authorization_methods = [
    "GET",
  ]
}
```

*Terraform initialized with* `terraform init`*with a valid configuration.*

[image]

*Executed* `terraform plan`:

[image]

*Deployed with the final changes using* `terraform apply`:

[image]

Refer [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_authorization_server#client_authentication_method) for the above used properties under authorization server of an APIM and their purpose.

Comment: Thank you, @Jahnavi. How we pass the Resource URL and "Authorization Name."?

Comment: Resource URL is nothing but client registration endpoint. Authorization name is a “name” property. @OneDeveloper

Comment: I have updated the question, can you check?

Comment: You can also use [`azurerm_api_management_named_value`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_named_value) to add an authorization for api management. Can you try with that once? @OneDeveloper